# Semigroup implies exponential

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-equations

Let $S :[0,1]\to \mathbb R^{n\times n}$ be a continuous function which satisfies
$$
S(0)=I \quad\text{and}\quad S(s+t)=S(s)S(t),
$$
for all $s,t\in[0,1]$ with $s+t\in[0,1]$. (Here $I$ is the identity matrix in $\mathbb R^{n\times n}$).

Show that there exists a matrix $A\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$, such that $S(t)=\mathrm{e}^{tA}$.

Comment. Once we show that $S$ is differentiable at $0$, then setting $A=S'(0)$, it is not hard to prove the above, as we would then have $S'(t)=AS(t),\,\,S(0)=I$, which is a system of ODEs with unique solution the exponential.

Comment: What part of the comment has you confused? Is that comment from the problem, or is that your comment?

Comment: The "Comment" is an attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: It's not really a "semigroup" if you only define it on $[0,1]$. You'd have to prove that it extends to a semigroup on all of $\mathbb R$...

Answer (score 4):

For $0<t<1$, define the integrated matrix   $H(t)x= \int_0^t S(w)x\,dw$.
Note that ${1\over t}H(t) x\to x$ as $t\to 0$, so for $t$ small enough, $H(t)$ is invertible. 
Now fix such a $t$.

Your semigroup is differentiable from the right on $H(t)(\mathbb{R}^n)=\mathbb{R}^n$ 
since direct calculations give
$${S(s)(H(t)x)-H(t)x\over s}\to (S(t)-I)x,$$ as $s\downarrow 0$. The required matrix is 
$A=(S(t)-I)H(t)^{-1}$.

Comment: Humble but important result, +1 from me. Is this part of some standard text book? I would like to know...

Comment: It is my own result, based on the standard fact that the generator of a strongly continuous semigroup is densely defined. This is usually proved using the resolvent, which are "smoothed" elements. Since the OP's "semigroup" is only defined for $0\leq t\leq 1$, I tried to adapt this idea by averaging instead of smoothing.

Comment: Well, it should be in a text book. I have seen similar "semigroups" in image analysis (or multi dimensional signal processing) all the time. Not exactly like this, but certainly close. Tnx!

Comment: @Byron.Schmuland, I am still confused by your use of *I* as opposed to *I* (identity) as used by the OP, could you please rephrase your answer, I still don't get it all :( ?

Comment: $I(t)$, not $I$, is the *integral* from $0$ to $t$ of $S(w)$. You can change the notation if you don't like it.

Comment: Did it, hope ok. Tnx.

Comment: @caya Thanks for the clearer notation!

Answer (score 0):

This may not be true; I will put my first impression and think about it. On a small neighborhood of the identity matrix we have a well-defined logarithm. So, taking $L(t) = \log S(t)$ we have the equation $L(s+t) = L(s) + L(t).$ This is [Cauchy's functional equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation) in each matrix entry.

The interesting thing is that a bad solution of Cauchy's  equation is unbounded on any interval. Maybe you can conclude that $L$ is linear because of that.

Nope: take a discontinuous solution in one variable, 
$$ g(s+t) = g(s) + g(t). $$

Take a fixed matrix you like, call it $B.$

Then define 
$$ S(t) = e^{g(t) B}.  $$

This solves $S(s+t) = S(s) S(t).$ But kind of bad. So the question becomes, does this violate any of your hypotheses?  Hmmm. Yes, I think it makes for a discontinuous map $S.$ I will leave this here, I think it is instructive...

Comment: Unclear whether "may not be true..." means there are cases where it is not true (in which case this is an answer) or "may not be true" means you aren't certain if it is true, in which case, it isn't an answer, just a comment...

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, still not sure, but long for a comment in any case.

Comment: I am afraid it is not correct. You say that: *So, taking $L(t) = \log S(t)$ we have the equation $L(s+t) = L(s) + L(t).$*  This is not necessarily true as logarithm of matrix is far from uniquely defined.

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis, right. I think there is a single-valued logarithm if you are in a mall neighborhood of the identity matrix. Anyway, I will leave it here as I said.

Answer (score 0):

This is an elementary proof that given *A* such that $S(1)=e^A$ - i.e. if $S(1)$ admits a logarithm, then $S(t)=e^{t A}$.

You can see from your definition that $S(1)=$ $S(m (1/m))=$ $S(1/m + ... + 1/m)=$ $S(1/m)...S(1/m)=$ $S(1/m)^m$, so $e^A=S(1/m)^m$ and therefore $S(1/m)=e^{A{1/m}}$. Therefore, $S(n/m)=e^{(n/m)A}$ by similar argument for all $0\le n/m \le 1$. Note that that case $n=0$ requires $S(0)=I$ as per hypothesis.

You have two continuous functions, $S$ and $e^{t A}$, that are equal on $\Bbb Q$, which is dense in $[0, 1]$. Therefore, they are equal on the whole interval.

*Update*

I like Schmuland's answer, and won't elaborate further.